# How can I cut and statistics the string in text plain document?

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

I have got a large text plain doc,The content please refer this pic 
[image]

```
cat textplain.txt|grep '^\.[\/[:alpha:]]*[\.\:][[:alpha:]]*'
```

I want the output result like below :

> ```
> ./external/selinux/libsepol/src/mls.c
> ./external/selinux/libsepol/src/handle.c
> ./external/selinux/libsepol/src/constraint.c
> ./external/selinux/libsepol/src/sidtab.c
> ./external/selinux/libsepol/src/nodes.c
> ./external/selinux/libsepol/src/conditiona.c
> ```

Question:
 What's should I do

Comment: How was the original file generated? Just regenerate it with the same grep expression, but add `-l` to only list files.

Comment: @PS.  `awk -F: '{print $1} input file '` this command work good. But the same string was print more than one times

Comment: @choroba `grep des -rn ./android/source/code`

Comment: try `awk -F: '!a[$1]++{print $1}'`

Comment: Or `cut -d : -f1 file | uniq`

Comment: use the `-o` option

Comment: Don't post input example as images, it's not searchable and we can't copy/paste it into answers

Answer (score 3):

Just regenerate the file with

```
grep -lr des ./android/source/code
```

- `-l` only lists the files with matches without showing their contents
- `-r` is still needed to search subdirectories
- `-n` has no influence on `-l`, so can be omitted. `-c` instead of `-l` would add the number of occurrences to each file name, but you'll probably want to `| grep -v :0` to skip the zeroes.

Or, use `cut` and `sort -u`:

```
cut -d: -f1 textplain.txt | sort -u
```

- `-d:` delimit columns by :
- `-f1` only output the first column
- `-u` output unique lines

Comment: Yeah, Thanks your feedback. However I can not access the android source code,(Only a large more than 500Mb text plain),

Comment: Good answer! Generating the correct output in the first place is better than sanitizing it afterwards. That pattern is seen too often.